# The Paris Review logo font?

Tags: font-identification

What is the font used in the Paris Review logo? WTF suggests Stone Serif, but the shapes are very different.
I've also tried fontspring.com, whatfontis.com, fonts.com matchers with no luck.
[image: logo]

Comment: Well, the _the_ is some variant of Garamond; but I don’t recognise the other one, either. Interesting personality it has (and yes, Stone Serif is _way_ off).

Comment: *Definitely* not a Stone variant :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I think all is in one font. It must be some sort of Garamond, just very unusual one.

Comment: Did you try other automated font id services besides WhatTheFont? If so, please mention as much in your question. Thanks!

Comment: It looks a lot like the title font for The New Yorker. http://www.newyorker.com/ Not *the same*, but very similar. Might be a relative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a 22 September 2010 [interview with the designer of the current website](http://www.theparisreview.org/blog/2010/09/22/jennifer-over-and-our-new-web-site/), Jennifer Over, the *Paris Review* logotype is not something you'll be able to download:

> We also really wanted to embrace certain design elements of the print magazine, like **the hand-rendered logotype**, some of the mid-century-modern typography and the frontispiece illustration by William Pène du Bois.

(Emphasis added.)

The same question was [asked on WTF](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/343093/) in 2010: it remains "unsolved".

Comment: I was afraid of that

Comment: @contemplator The [Imperator font](http://www.dafont.com/imperator.font?text=PARIS+REVIEW) -- a freebie on DaFont -- isn't a million miles away. It might have some issues design-wise, but perhaps worth a look and you can make up your own mind whether it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Late reply as it's interesting. While custom, this looks a lot like Fournier, the Roman du Roi or some of the other fonts of the eighteenth century. The tell is the curled leg of the 'R', which is an eighteenth/late-seventeeth-century feature, and the narrow, almost monoline serifs, although the 'h' with its leg folding inwards is more sixteenth. Fournier has been digitised by [Monotype](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/fournier-mt/), [Typofonderie](https://typofonderie.com/fonts/ps-fournier-family/) and [Joshua Darden](https://www.dardenstudio.com/typefaces/corundum_text), so you have a bit of choice. [Fleischmann's types](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/fleischman-bt-pro/) are also in the same mood.

Answer (score -2):

Estienne—or some slight variation of it.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Can you please a screenshot for a fast proof?

Comment: If you mean [this one](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/solotype/estienne/normal/), you’re quite unfathomably wrong. It doesn’t have a single feature in common with the Paris Review font and looks about as different from it as it is possible for a font to look.